# Use R's Reduce to sum up identically named elements for each element in a list

Tags: r, reduce

I have this list in R

```
> test
[[1]]
[[1]]$right
[1] FALSE

[[1]]$left
[1] FALSE


[[2]]
[[2]]$right
[1] TRUE

[[2]]$left
[1] FALSE
```

which can quickly be created with this dput

```
list(list(right = FALSE, left = FALSE), list(right = TRUE, left = FALSE))
```

Now I want to sum up the `right` and the `left` elements in each element of the `test`-list, so that I end up with a list of two elements like this:

```
> res
$right
[1] 1

$left
[1] 0
```

I thought R's `Reduce` would be a good option for that (although I'm open for any advice), but I could not figure out the code. I tried the following, yet it did not work...

```
Reduce(function(x){
     r = sum(x[["right"]]) 
     l = sum(x[["left"]]) 
     v = list(r, v)
 }, test)
```

I get this error

```
Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])
```

And I think I am having some misconception in my head...

Comment: Please note that the function passed to `Reduce` must take two arguments i.e. `function(x,y)`

Comment: BTW, you have a typo, `list(r, v)` should probably be `list(r, l)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `unlist` the lists and coerce `rowSums` `as.list`, which might be more efficient.

```
as.list(rowSums(sapply(test, unlist)))
# $right
# [1] 1
# 
# $left
# [1] 0
```

---

*Data:*

```
test <- list(list(right=FALSE, left=FALSE), list(right=TRUE, left=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 4):

Reduce expects a function that accepts two arguments. It will get the result of the previous value of `Reduce` and a new element from the vector you pass to `Reduce`

```
Reduce(\(x,y) list(left = x$left + y$left, right = x$right + y$right), test)
```

Personally, I would use `sapply` (or `Map` if you want) to first get the `left`/`right` elements and then pass those to `sum`:

```
sapply(test, \(x) x$left) |> sum()
```

A version with `Map` and `Reduce` would be:

```
Map(\(x) x$left, test) |> Reduce(f = \(x, y) x + y)
```

or

```
Map(\(x) x$left, test) |> Reduce(f = `+`)
```

Comment: thank you very much!! Maybe it's a bit early and my brain just not working, but I wanted to ask why you put the backslash in all those functions?

Comment: @Lenn that is the new short way of defining (lambda) functions. So instead of `function(x,y) x+y` you can do `\(x,y) x+y` . Saves a few letters.

Comment: ahhh thank you so much!! So there is the old `function(x,x)`, there is "tidyverse"s" `~.x`-style and then there is this now too?

Answer (score 3):

Using `purrr`

```r
library(purrr)
sides <- c("left", "right")

setNames(sides, sides) |>
    map(~(map_int(test, chuck, .x))) |>
    map(reduce, `+`)

##> $left
##> [1] 0
##> 
##> $right
##> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to aggregate per names, you can `unlist` and use `tapply` to sum by names:

```r
ll <- list(list(right = FALSE, left = FALSE), list(right = TRUE, left = FALSE))
un <- unlist(ll)
tapply(un, names(un), FUN = sum)
# left right 
#    0     1
```

---

You can transpose first:

```r
purrr::transpose(ll) |>
  lapply(Reduce, f = sum)

# $right
# [1] 1
# 
# $left
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the same except that they produce a named vector, an xtabs/table object or a data.frame respectively.  In all of them we unlist the input and stack it into a two column data frame.  Then we use `xtabs() |> c()`, `xtabs()` or `aggregate`.

```
# named vector output
L |>
  unlist() |>
  stack() |>
  xtabs() |>
  c()
## right  left 
##     1     0 

# xtabs/table output
L |>
  unlist() |>
  stack() |>
  xtabs()
## ind
## right  left 
##     1     0 

# data frame output
L |>
  unlist() |>
  stack() |>
  aggregate(values ~ ind, data = _, sum)
##     ind values
## 1 right      1
## 2  left      0
```

### Note

```
L <- list(list(right = FALSE, left = FALSE), list(right = TRUE, left = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this approach to count the rights and lefts of the list

```
a_list <- list(list(right = FALSE, left = FALSE),
               list(right = TRUE, left = FALSE))

library(rlist)

(result <- sapply(c(
  "right",
  "left"
), function(x) {
  rlist::list.count(
    a_list,
    eval(parse(text = x))
  )
}))
```

```
right  left 
    1     0
```